# PHP Soap WebsService, how to redirect the client

Tags: php, soap

I'm doing a PHP Single Sign On (SSO) web service in SOAP.

But this web service is built separate to the site. Meaning there's a client that tries to single sign on, there's a web service that authenticates the client and redirect to the destination site.

So in the web service, when I do a Location redirect, I just get a soap fault. I wanna know if it is even possible to redirect the client using SOAP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making the SOAP server to send a HTTP location header to initialize a redirect makes no sense in your case. Because it redirects the SOAP client so that it sends the SOAP request to another SOAP server. In your case the redirect location is not a SOAP server however.

In your case you just need to tell the SSO client that the user has been signed on and that's it. The site then know that the user has been signed on.

When you want to redirect the user as well to somewhere, return the redirect location as well and then the PHP script that has the SOAP client can do the redirect. That should do it.

See as well: [Web Service redirection with custom SOAP Header (asp.net)](http://forums.asp.net/t/1442999.aspx/1)